# How to get total working time group by month?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, pivot

I need to calculate the time spent by some workers in year 2014, and need to group (and sum) by month.
Every row should be like this

```
Worker 1 | Tot Time HH:MM:SS (Jan) | Tot Time HH:MM:SS (Feb) | etc... | Tot Time Year
Worker 2 | Tot Time HH:MM:SS (Jan) | Tot Time HH:MM:SS (Feb) | etc... | Tot Time Year
Worker 3 | Tot Time HH:MM:SS (Jan) | Tot Time HH:MM:SS (Feb) | etc... | Tot Time Year
```

My MySQL DB is like this:

```
id_worker (int, primary key), in_datetime (DATETIME), out_datetime (DATETIME)
```

Can someone please help me? I only manage to calculate the totale time in one year.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Its scenario of using Pivot and UnPivot in SQL which are used to return rows into columns and columns into rows. But not sure of their equivalents in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_worker, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 1 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS JanWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 2 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS FebWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 3 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS MarWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 4 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS AprWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 5 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS MayWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 6 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS JunWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 7 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS JulWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 8 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS AugWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 9 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS SepWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 10 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS OctWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 11 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS NovWorkingTime, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MonthNo = 12 THEN workingTime ELSE 0 END)) AS DecWorkingTime 
FROM (SELECT id_worker, MONTH(in_datetime) MonthNo, 
             SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, in_datetime, out_datetime)) AS workingTime
      FROM tableA 
      WHERE YEAR(in_datetime) = 2014
      GROUP BY id_worker, MonthNo
    ) AS A
GROUP BY id_worker
```